# Can I reprioritize the queue in Ubuntu One?

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one

Some relatively small text files on my netbook that I use every day 8 hours/day are a week out of sync. `u1sdtool --waiting-content` shows a huge number of photos on the list to be uploaded before one of the text file to be downloaded.

Is there a way to move the text file up to get it processed sooner? Seems like it has been taking weeks for the photos to synchronize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the order, in which Ubuntu One downloads the files. I'm not even sure you can chose to skip certain file formats.

Is it possible for you to sign in on the web, and fetch them directly instead? If you place them in the correct folders, there might be a chance they sync before Ubuntu One download new files.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is a good idea. Instead I kept my netbook humming along all night and got the backlog cleared by morning.

Answer (score 2):

I'm half-answering this question with a tiny script that should work **in theory**.

It searches for a string in --waiting-content, get the IDs and sends them to --schedule-next.

Sadly, **it doesn't work** because the "u1sdtool --schedule-next" command is failing on a dbus bug and because of [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/720802), I don't see a bright future for it.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 ]
    then
    search=$1
    else
    echo "You need to provide a search string: u1up <search>"
    exit
fi
FirstResult=$(u1sdtool --waiting-content | grep -i $search)
if [ $FirstResult ]
    then
    node_id=$(echo $FirstResult | sed -n 's/.*node_id=\(.*\)\ share.*/\1/p')
    share_id=$(echo $FirstResult | sed -n 's/.*share_id=\(.*\)\ path.*/\1/p')
    path=$(echo $FirstResult | sed -n 's/.*path=\(.*\)/\1/p')

    echo "Attempting to prioritize $path ..."
    u1sdtool --schedule-next=$share_id $node_id

    else
    echo "Your search did not match any file waiting in the Ubuntu One queue."
    exit
fi
```

That was an interesting question!

Comment: Thanks for the script. Perhaps if the bug you mentioned gets fixed this will be quite useful to prioritize synchronizing work files first.